# Why am I getting the error in a loop that reoccurs at a single particular iteration every run-time? (Binary Queries problem from HackerEarth)

Tags: java, loops, binary

I'm trying to solve this question:
Binary Queries,
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/range-query-2/

Question summary:
N digits of binary numbers are given; Q queries are then given.
Two types of queries:
"0 X": Flip the Xth bit
"1 L R": Print if binary no. formed by L to R(position) is odd or even.

Simple solution is to check only rightmost bit; if it's 1, the number is odd, else, even.

My code throws "Wrong answer" every time; 
however, IN ALL TEST CASES, there's ONLY ONE wrong output, and this wrong output happens EXACTLY 99 lines before the total number of output lines*. 
There seems to be no other pattern.

*I tried flipping output when I reach (Q-99)th query to check; however, there's no way to find number of output queries without storing all queries, since query type[0] has no output, only type[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syXE9.jpg) has an output. Thus, Q cannot be used.

Images:  [All testcases fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syXE9.jpg)   [Eg.1 The only line of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Zt1.jpg)   [Eg.2 Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpGyA.jpg).

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inpArr[] = (br.readLine().split("\\s"));
    int n=Integer.parseInt(inpArr[0]);              //number of digits
    int q=Integer.parseInt(inpArr[1]);              //number of queries
    //read binary digits w/o space, and store them as chars
    String binArrStr=br.readLine().replace(" ",""); 
    char[] binArr=binArrStr.toCharArray();          
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<q;i++)                                //all queries
    {
        String query[]=br.readLine().split("\\s");           //read the query 
        if(query[0].equals("1"))                            //Flip the bit if query[0]=1
        {
            if(binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]=='1')    //take position(query[1]) as int and flip
                binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]='0';
            else
                binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]='0';
        }
        else                                               //Print odd or even if query[0]=0
        {
            //query[1] is leftmost bit.
            //Sufficient to check only the bit in rightmost position, given by 
            //3rd argument(Rightmost bit) which is query[2]
            //If rightmost bit==1, ODD, else EVEN
            if(binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[2])-1]=='1')   
                System.out.println("ODD");
            else
                System.out.println("EVEN");
        }
    }

}
```

I could skip this problem, but it's better to know why exactly this happens, I think.

Comment: Your second bit-flip should be 1, not 0.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the pattern threw me off! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(query[0].equals("1"))                            //Flip the bit if query[0]=1
    {
        if(binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]=='1')    //take position(query[1]) as int and flip
            binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]='0';
        else
            binArr[Integer.parseInt(query[1])-1]='0';
 }
```

in your if statement you checked that if it's 1 then flip it to 0 but in your else block you are not flipping the number to 1 because else block will come to action if the number is 0. Hence you are only partially flipping.

Here is my solution

import java.util.Scanner;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int q = scan.nextInt();
    int[] bits = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        bits[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= q; i++) {
        if (scan.nextInt() == 1) {
            int index = scan.nextInt();
            if (bits[index] == 0) bits[index]++;
            else bits[index]--;
        } else {
            int lIndex = scan.nextInt();
            int rIndex = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(bits[rIndex] == 0 ? "EVEN" : "ODD");
        }
    }


}
```

}